# is there a HTML scraper in jQuery like Simple DOM Parser in PHP?

Tags: jquery, html, parsing

I have use Simple DOM Parser in PHP but since I am using jQuery in my site, I'm thinking of using something like a plugin in jQuery to parse a HTML page. Is there any?

Comment: What does `parse an HTML page` mean in this context?

Comment: Additionally, I'd strongly suggest you accept some answers to your past questions as well.

Comment: Why will you be parsing the page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `$('your html')` and apply any jquery functions you want. Also [Pure JavaScript HTML Parser](http://ejohn.org/blog/pure-javascript-html-parser/) by John Resig can be useful for you.